# PHP array : sum elements of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array like this :

```
array(2)(
['id'] => "59898441545",
['total'] => 
array(
[0] => 2,
[1] => 5
[2] => 10
[3] => 35
)
);
```

I would like the returned array to be the same but, the key "total" to not be a aarray but the sum of all the precedemtn value like this :

```
array(2)(
['id] => "59898441545",
['total'] => 52 // the sum of the precedent elements
);
```

P.S : the number of elements in the "total array" may change 
Any help ? thx in advance

Comment: and where exactly is the problem, that prevents you from using a simple loop or any other way to sum up an array?

Comment: [array_sum](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp) seems simple enough

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$youarray['total'] = array_sum($youarray['total']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($mainArr['total'] as $arr) {
    $sum += $arr;
}
$mainArr['total'] = $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
<?php
$data = array('id' => "59898441545",
'total' => array(
        0 => 2,
        1 => 5,
        2 => 10,
        3 => 35
)
);
 $data['total'] = array_sum($data['total']);
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = array("a" => 1.2, "b" => 2.3, "c" => 3.4); 
echo "sum(b) = " . array_sum($b);
*Output* : sum(b) = 6.9
```